# NoSql database suitable for long value

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am looking to use NoSql database for my applications. I have searched internet and found Berkeley DB, Mongodb, redis, Tokyo cabinet etc. There are some suggestions, usecases which database to use when. Some useful links i find are

1. http://perfectmarket.com/blog/not_only_nosql_review_solution_evaluation_guide_chart
2. http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

But i didn't find which database performs good when value(in key-value pair) is very big like 1 MB or something.

MongoDB looks good to me because of its query feature. How it performs when you store very big documents.

Comment: What's your use case for the documents?  Could you explain what you're going to do with the documents that you are storing?  Why is a SQL database not appropriate for you?

Comment: I am storing a entity and its related properties. If i use RDMS, then it will be stored in many tables. When showing a page, i need to pull table from many tables which requires join which is time consuming. This is my personal project(facebook app). Many websites uses nosql kind of database. I also heard a lot of nosql so try to build applications to get feel how really they are useful.

Comment: So what sort of operations are you going to perform?  If it's something like key/value lookup (or map/reduce operations) then a NoSQL store is a great idea.  If you're going to be doing relational queries, then a relational database is the way to go.

Comment: It is mostly key/value lookup.

Answer (score 2):

RavenDB has the notion of Attachemnts. In a document, instead of having a property 1MB in size (usually a byte array), you'd put a minimalistic document with data you want to Map/Reduce on and save that large data bite as an attachment. That speeds up things very well.